# Can't get Notifications Icon on the notifications Pop up in Android Flutter with FCM messaging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

After some time I was able to set up my notifications which are enabled on Foreground and Background
this is my code to implement Local and FCM notifications but even I have setting up my icon into the notifications is not shown.

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
    configLocalNotification();
    FlutterBackground.initialize();
  }



  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? showNotification(message['notification'])
          : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
      return ;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      return Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
    },         onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      return;
    },
        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
    );



    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Consultant')
          .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .update({'deviceToken': token});
    }).catchError((err) {
      //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
    });
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen(payload: payload,)),
    );
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app'
          : 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);
    print(message['body'].toString());
    print(json.encode(message));

    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(2, message['title'].toString(),
    //     message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
    //     payload: json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      3, ' Hai ricevuto un messaggio  ', 'Controlla subito le Tue notifiche ', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x',
    );
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
```

as you can see I should get `@mipmap/ic_launcher` icon which doesnt...

I need to specify also into my firebase function?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("Notifications/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
      const name = snapshot.get("name");
      const subject = snapshot.get("subject");
      const token = snapshot.get("token");

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "" + name,
          body: "" + subject,
          sound: "default",
        },
        data: {
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      };

      return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
    });
```

this is also my AndroidManifest...

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="My APP"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
```

I just get as icon a background grey color square...
I tried to add ```

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
          
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

but I get error building the APK:

```
Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to add this lib to your [launcher icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

- add flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0 to your pubspec.yaml
- run flutter pub get
- uder dev_dependencies: add this code
- flutter pub get
- flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

after that try to uninstall and reinstall and try to send the notification again the icon should be visible

```js
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```